# How to translate "highly swept" when used for an aircraft

Tags: meaning, usage

The following paragraph discusses RQ-180 aircraft. What is the meaning of *highly swept* that has been used as an adjective for body?

> The aircraft uses a version of
>   Northrop’s stealthy “cranked-kite” de-
>   sign, as does the X-47B, with a highly
>   swept centerbody and long, slender
>   outer wings. Northrop Grumman en-
>   gineers publicly claimed (before the
>   launch of the classified program) that
>   the cranked-kite is scalable and adapt-
>   able, in contrast to the B-2’s shape, which
>   has an unbroken leading edge. The RQ-
>   180’s centerbody length and volume can
>   be greater relative to the vehicle’s size.

I don't understand what *sweep* means in aircraft wing context. Another example follows:

> Maintaining a
>   high degree of laminar flow on a **swept
>   wing** is an achievement in itself, because
>   spanwise air flow tends to induce turbulence and is not made any easier by possible spillage from overwing inlets.

Having looked up the entry "sweep", I don't seem to understand what it means with *wing*.

Comment: I think it's this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swept_wing.

Comment: Aeronautics. (of an airfoil or its leading or trailing edge) to project from the fuselage at an angle rearward or forward of a line perpendicular to the longitudinal axis of the aircraft. def 20 - http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/swept

Answer (score 1):

In this instance I think these are two separate things. The body of the the RQ-180 is extremely aerodynamic, whereas a swept wing is a type of wing design, like delta wing.

Comment: In this case, because this design is basically a flying-wing design, the body is considered to be swept as well. I.e., the leading edge of the body projects away from the aircraft centerline at a rearward angle.  The wings project outward relative to the centerline at a rearward sweep angle as well.

Answer (score 1):

A "swept wing" is a design in which the wing doesn't project straight out from the fuselage; instead, there's an overall angle between the two. Here's a "straight wing" (i.e. not swept), in which the wing overall is at right angles to the fuselage:

[image: straight]

Here's a swept wing, in which the wing is "swept back" (while the first wing basically goes left-right, this one points generally backwards):

[image: swept]

Some wings are at more of an angle than others (they're "swept back" further). A highly swept wing is one which is at a sharper angle to the fuselage, like so:

[image: highly swept]

The RQ-180 is a "flying wing" design, which means that the whole fuselage of the aircraft provides lift. The leading edge of the center of the aircraft is at a sharp angle, like the highly swept wing example. Technically, that doesn't quite make it highly swept (sweep angle applies to wings, not to leading edges), but because it's a sharp angle it *looks* like a highly swept wing, so the author just used the term.

Comment: I guess this wing resembles a traditional sweeper, hence the name.